# Custom Post Types on Category Archive Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, custom-taxonomy

I am using this code to first display each category. Problem is when i visit custom taxonomy category archive pages, its show all category post. I don't understand why? Please solve this code.
Custom post register and taxonomy register code `(custom-posts.php)`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'thebdjob_theme_custom_post' );
function thebdjob_theme_custom_post() {
    register_post_type( 'jobsposts',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Jobs Posts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'jobsposts' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Jobs' ),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit')
            ),
            'public' => true,
             'rewrite'            => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
     'query_var'          => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes'),
        )
    );
}   


register_taxonomy(
        'jobs_categories',
        'jobsposts',
        array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'label'                 => 'Jobs Categories',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'              => 'jobs_categories', 
                'with_front'        => true 
                )
            )
    );    
}

add_action( 'init', 'thebdjob_custom_post_taxonomy' );
```

And my `archive.php` file code :

```
<?php global $post;
 $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type'=> 'jobsposts',  'post_status'=> 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', );
```

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

```
<?php 
$company_name= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'company_name', true);
$jobs_keyskills= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobs_keyskills', true); 
$jobs_description= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobs_description', true);
$jobs_experience= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobs_experience', true); 
$jobs_location= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobs_location', true); 
?>


<div class="cat_post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <h4><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo     get_the_title(); ?></a></h4>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <div class="jtitle">
                <?php echo $company_name; ?>
            </div>
        </div>     <?php the_title(); ?>
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <span class="stitle">Keyskills :</span>
                <span itemore="description">
                    <?php echo $jobs_keyskills; ?>
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <span class="stitle">Keyskills :</span>
                <span itemore="description">
                    <?php echo $jobs_description; ?>
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <span class="stitle">Location :</span>
                <span itemore="description">
                    <?php echo $jobs_location; ?>
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-cat-1">
            <span class="stitle">Experience :</span>
                <span itemore="description">
                    1-3yrs
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Are all the posts on the category page from that category or also others?

Comment: every category page show same post.

Comment: Which post is this the correct one or is this a category?

Comment: This is going to display all posts regardless of Category. I need to make sure I have the category change depending on the page.